# A large switch statement or several small switch statements?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am wondering if there any performance different between a large switch statement and several small switch statements.

Large switch statement with hundreds of cases.

```
switch(quest){
            case 1: quest1(); break;
            case 2: quest2(); break;
            .
            .
            .
            case 196: quest196(); break;
            case 197: quest197(); break;
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

or several smaller switch statement with 30 cases each.

```
if (quest <= 30) {
        switch (quest) {
            case 1: quest1(); break;    
            case 2: quest2(); break;    
            case 3: quest3(); break;
            .
            .
            case 30: quest30(); break;
            default: 
                return;
        }
    } else if (quest <= 60) {
        switch (quest) {
            case 31: quest31(); break;  
            case 32: quest32(); break;  
            case 33: quest33(); break;
            .
            . 
            .
            case 60: quest60(); break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    } 
  .
  .
  .
```

Also, I know reflection will be a lot easier to code, but will that cause a large overhead?

something like this.

```
try {
            Method method =Logic.class.getMethod("quest"+quest);
            method.invoke(this);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be less worried about micro-optimization and more worried that your design is not OO.

Comment: I believe java will compile a switch statement to either a jump table or a binary search depending on which it thinks would be best, so there should be no need to do that sort of thing yourself.

Comment: Definitely agree with Kevin.  But I think having just one switch is more efficient, because each switch statement should find an address in a table to jump to, and then go there--constant time.  Another switch just does the same thing twice.  The amount of time isn't enough to worry about in almost all cases.  And nested switches don't make your code more readable.

Comment: Hi Kevin, so how should I change this to an OO design? The class currently take integer range from 1 to 600, and every task need to do some specific task.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a large `switch` and a chain of `if`/`then`/`else` statements that include smaller `switch` is that a single `switch` will find the code to execute in a single lookup, while a chain of conditionals may need several individual checks before arriving at the `switch` statement of interest. Once the `switch` statement is found, it takes roughly the same time to do a dispatch, almost no matter how many `case` labels there are. A single `switch` statement is also more readable, so I would prefer it to a chain of conditionals.

Although reflection does have an overhead, it is not terrible, so if your `questNNN` methods are not extremely fast, the overhead of reflection is not going to matter much. You could even speed it up by preparing an array of `Method` objects, and populate it upfront to avoid the `Logic.class.getMethod("quest"+quest)` calls at the time when you dispatch the call.

Finally, you could create an array of `Runnable` objects, and encapsulate calls of `questNNN` inside them:

```
Runnable[] dispatch = new Runnable[] {
    new Runnable() { public void run() { quest0(); } }
,   new Runnable() { public void run() { quest1(); } }
,   new Runnable() { public void run() { quest2(); } }
,   new Runnable() { public void run() { quest3(); } }
,   new Runnable() { public void run() { quest4(); } }
...
,   new Runnable() { public void run() { quest59(); } }
,   new Runnable() { public void run() { quest60(); } }
};
```

Now you can call `dispatch[NNN].run()` to call your `questNNN` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so will reflection do any better than the switch statement?

Comment: @user2304633 Generally, reflection is slower than just about anything else...but you will need to test it for your particular use case

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to optimize do it for the programmers that will come after you. Use a proper structure that will make it obviously optimal for speed while patently clear and simple.

```
interface Quest {

    void quest();
}
static Set<Quest> allQuests = new HashSet<>();

enum MontyPythonQuests implements Quest {

    MakeMeAShrubbery {
                @Override
                public void quest() {
                    System.out.println("Build me a SHRUBBERY!!!!!");
                }
            },
    SeekTheHolyGrail {
                @Override
                public void quest() {
                    System.out.println("Brave Sir Basil ran away!");
                }
            };

    @Override
    public void quest() {
        // Simplistic default implementation just prints the name of the enum.
        System.out.println(this.name());
    }

    MontyPythonQuests() {
        // All quests are added to the list.
        allQuests.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: But there are hundreds of different quest type, so should I create couple hundreds of new classes? I feel it will be harder to change something later.

Comment: @user2304633 - Absolutely not - each `enum` is a quest! I have made them incredibly simple here because you gave no example of a questxx method. I have expanded a little on the quests to be more obvious.

Comment: @user2304633 - You can also have multiple `enums`, each holding a group of similar quests.